# Integrating java and .net dll using JNI

Tags: java, c#, c++, .net, dll

I am doing a small project it is a interoperability of java and .net dll.

Focus:

I just have a java file which calls the .net dll which is created by using C# and CPP and MCPP..

The program is just a hello world Program..

I just refer the below mentioned sites.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/378826/How-to-wrap-a-Csharp-library-for-use-in-Java

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13093/C-method-calls-within-a-Java-program

Finally I just get some ideas and finally did this with some errors.

Coding:

```
#using "mscorlib.dll"
#using "CSharpHelloWorld.netmodule"

using namespace System;

public __gc class HelloWorldC
{
    public:

    // Provide .NET interop and garbage collecting to the pointer.
    CSharpHelloWorld __gc *t;

    HelloWorldC() {

        t = new CSharpHelloWorld();

        // Assign the reference a new instance of the object
    }

 // This inline function is called from the C++ Code
    void callCSharpHelloWorld() {

        t->displayHelloWorld();
    }
};
```

Errors:

```
Error   1   error C4980: '__gc' : use of this keyword requires /clr:oldSyntax command line option   

Error   2   error C3699: 'interior_ptr' : cannot use this indirection on type 'CSharpHelloWorld'    

Error   3   error C2750: 'CSharpHelloWorld' : cannot use 'new' on the reference type; use 'gcnew' instead   

Error   4   error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'CSharpHelloWorld *' to 'CSharpHelloWorld ^' 11  WindowsComponentProject

Error   5   error C2011: 'HelloWorldC' : 'class' type redefinition  6   WindowsComponentProject

Error   6   error C3699: '*' : cannot use this indirection on type 'HelloWorldC'    18  WindowsComponentProject

Error   7   error C2750: 'HelloWorldC' : cannot use 'new' on the reference type; use 'gcnew' instead    18  WindowsComponentProject

Error   8   error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'HelloWorldC *' to 'HelloWorldC ^'    18  WindowsComponentProject

Error   9   error C2027: use of undefined type 'HelloWorldC'        21  WindowsComponentProject

Error   10  error C2227: left of '->callCSharpHelloWorld' must point to class/struct/union/generic type  21 WindowsComponentProject
```

I just seek some sites for the solution to change the properties of CLR but it doesn't works kindly help me over it.. thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 0):

You are using old Managed C++ syntax. 
New one is called C++/CLI.

You create a reference type by prefixing the class declaration with `ref` keyword. Use `^` to declare a reference variable as in `CSharpHelloWorld^ t`.
`gcnew` is what you use to create an object in managed heap.

You should modify your class as shown below.

```
using namespace System;

public ref class HelloWorldC { 

public:

// Provide .NET interop and garbage collecting to the pointer.
CSharpHelloWorld^ t;

HelloWorldC() {

    t = gcnew CSharpHelloWorld();

    // Assign the reference a new instance of the object
}

// This inline function is called from the C++ Code
void callCSharpHelloWorld() {

    t->displayHelloWorld();
}
};
```

Comment: Error 1 error C2011: 'HelloWorldC' : 'class' type redefinition \HelloWorld.h 6 WindowsComponentProject

Comment: Error 2 error C3699: '*' : cannot use this indirection on type 'HelloWorldC' \HelloWorld.cpp 18 WindowsComponentProject

Comment: Error 3 error C2750: 'HelloWorldC' : cannot use 'new' on the reference type; use 'gcnew' instead \HelloWorld.cpp 18 WindowsComponentProject

Comment: The Problem is I cannot load the header file properly, May I know how to load the header files..